# Dismiss or remove previous modally presented view controller as soon as the next one appear modally

Tags: ios, swift, uiviewcontroller

My target include a lot view need to present different view modally base on each user action. Here what I want to do to get cleaner view hierarchy and better user experience.

> 1. ***Root View Controller present First View Controller modally***
> 2. ***When I clicked button on the First View Controller, then the Second View Controller appear modally over it.***
> 3. ***As soon as the Second View Controller did appear, I want to dismiss or remove the first one from view hierarchy.***

Can I do that? **If so**, how should i do it?

**If not**, what is the right way to solve this out cause I will present many modally presented view controllers over each view. I think even if I want to dismiss current view, the previous one will still remain appear when current one dismiss.

**UPDATE :**

> **VC1 (Root) > VC 2 (which was present modally) > VC 3 (which was**
>   **present modally over VC 2)**

When i dismiss `VC3`, the `VC2` is still on view memory. So, I don't want to appear `VC2` as soon as I dismiss `VC3` and instead I want to see `VC1` by removing or dismissing `VC2` from view hierarchy.

[image]

***WANT* : At the image, when I dismiss the blue,I don't want see the pink in my view memory and I want to remove it as soon as the blue one appear.**

That's what i want to do.

Any Help?Thanks.

Comment: So, if I'm not mistaking, what are you trying to do is presenting as follows: vc1->vc2->vc3 and when dismissing vc3 you want to be in vc1, right?

Comment: Sort of it right....but here what i want to do. root>vc1>vc2>vc3 and when i dismiss vc3 there should not be vc1 and vc2 in memory view hierarchy

Comment: I assume that the root should be vc1...

Comment: @AhmadF, if so, my bad..

Comment: @AhmadF , I tried like this : https://puu.sh/t1jji/a760109c29.png. It worked but doesn't seem the right way if you set animation to true. And you will see vc2 is still on memory.

Comment: ok, to make sure that I'm gonna give you a useful answer, last question: do you think that you want to present the ViewControllers fully programmatically or by using segues?

Comment: @AhmadF, anything will do. But, at my code I used segues

Comment: Is it about the UI? or is it ok to show that the pink vc has been dismissed? because actually it has been removed form the stack of the viewControllers.

Comment: Yeah, my UI don't let me see the pink one. That's why..

Answer (score 13, accepted):

So, let's assume that you have a storyboard similar to:

[image]

What should happens is:

- Presenting the the second ViewController (from the first ViewController).
- Presenting the the third ViewController (from the second ViewController).
- dismissing to the first ViewController (from the third ViewController).

In the third ViewController button's action:

```
@IBAction func tapped(_ sender: Any) {
    presentingViewController?.presentingViewController?.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
}
```

As you can see, by accessing the [presentingViewController](https://developer.apple.com/reference/uikit/uiviewcontroller/1621430-presentingviewcontroller) of the current ViewController, you can dismiss the previous hierarchy of the view controllers:

> The view controller that presented this view controller.

By implementing `presentingViewController?.presentingViewController?` that means that: the presented of the presented current ViewController :)

It might seem a little bit confusing, but it is pretty simple.

So the output should be like (I added background colors to the viewControllers -as vc1: orange, vc2: black and vc3: light orange- to make it appears clearly):

[image]

**EDIT:**

If you are asking to remove the ViewController(s) in the middle (which in this example the second ViewController), [dismiss(animated:completion:)](https://developer.apple.com/reference/uikit/uiviewcontroller/1621505-dismiss) does this automatically:

> If you present several view controllers in succession, thus building a
>   stack of presented view controllers, calling this method on a view
>   controller lower in the stack dismisses its immediate child view
>   controller and all view controllers above that child on the stack.
>   When this happens, only the top-most view is dismissed in an animated
>   fashion; any intermediate view controllers are simply removed from the
>   stack. The top-most view is dismissed using its modal transition
>   style, which may differ from the styles used by other view controllers
>   lower in the stack.

Referring to what are you asking:

> I think even if I want to dismiss current view, the previous one will
>   still remain appear when current one dismiss.

I think that appears clearly on the UI (and I find it ok), but as mentioned in the `dismiss` documentation discussion, both the third and the second will be removed from the stack. That's the right way.

Comment: I think it was the same as  => self.view.window?.rootViewController?.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil).

Comment: So, did it give the expected result? is that what are you trying to achieve?

Comment: I am sorry to say that was not. I completely want to remove vc2 from view memory and it will be vc1>vc3 when vc3 appear.

Comment: it's ok, so what do want is after dismissing to vc, you want to go directly to vc3, right?

Comment: Really useful information for me...I guess there is no other way then...Thanks

Answer (score 3):

Here is my opinion in different perspective,

> 1. ***Root View Controller present Second View Controller***
> 2. ***Add FirstView onto Second View***
> 3. ***Dismiss FirstView Controller when button pressed.***

[image]

Second View Controller,

```
class ViewController: UIViewController, FirstViewControllerProtocol {

    weak var firstViewController: FirstViewController?

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        print("Not initiated: \(firstViewController)")

        firstViewController  = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil).instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "FirstViewController") as? FirstViewController
        addChildViewController(firstVC!)
        firstViewController?.delegate = self
        view.addSubview((firstViewController?.view)!)

        print("Initiated: \(firstViewController)")
    }

    func dismiss() {
        firstViewController?.view.removeFromSuperview()
        firstViewController?.removeFromParentViewController()

    }
}
```

FirstViewController,

```
protocol FirstViewControllerProtocol {
    // Use protocol/delegate to communicate within two view controllers
    func dismiss() 
}

class FirstViewController: UIViewController {

    var delegate: FirstViewControllerProtocol?

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
    }

    @IBAction func dismiss(_ sender: Any) {
        delegate?.dismiss()
    }

    deinit {
        print("BYE")
    }

}
```

Comment: I will give a try. Thanks.

Comment: Also, I add some log messages. when dismiss FirstViewController, deinit will be called and free the memory.

Comment: I really don't understand what's that mean...I think @IBAction func dismiss should include at second vc? If you don't mind can you please post answer with 3 vc ? vc1(root)> vc2 > vc3. Thanks

Comment: I mean when i dismiss vc3, vc2 should not be at memory and instead go to vc1. That's what i meant in my question.

Comment: It sounds like that your scenario is vc1(root) > navigationController (vc2 > vc 3) ?  when dismiss vc2 or vc3, it returns vc1.

Answer (score 2):

What you want is an "unwind segue":

https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/featuredarticles/ViewControllerPGforiPhoneOS/UsingSegues.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007457-CH15-SW8

https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/technotes/tn2298/_index.html

It allows you to dismiss multiple view controllers at the same time, without having to know how many there are in the stack.

In VC1 you would implement an `IBAction` called (for instance) `unwindToRoot`. Then in the storyboard for VC3, you wire up your Done button to the `Exit` object and choose the `unwindToRoot` action.

When that button is pressed, the system will dismiss all the view controllers it needs to bring you back to VC1.

This is better than calling `presentingViewController?.presentingViewController?.dismiss()`, because VC3 doesn't need to know anything about the view controller hierarchy underneath it.

Comment: I've found this creates odd animations when unwinding from modally presented VCs. The unwind redoes the modal animations in reverse, and it's really weird.