# Show ViewController and dismiss first

Tags: ios, swift

I've got one view controller "A" which presents modally another view controller B.

In storyboard it would look like this:

```
UIViewController "A" -> UINavigationViewController "B" -> rootViewController" "C"
```

My goal is to present B and hide A, how can I achieve that?

I tried setting property in C and there dismiss A, but it's not working, because I dismissed C and left A.

**AViewController**

```
override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
        if segue.identifier == "showSomething" {
            if let destination = segue.destination as? UINavigationController {
                if let viewController = destination.viewControllers.first as? CViewController {
                    viewController.delegate = self
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

**CViewController**

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        self.delegate.dismiss(animated: false)
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Dismissing presenting View Controller will -also- automatically  dismisses the presented View Controller in its hierarchy.

To make it more clear, let's consider that you have three ViewControllers: `A`, `B` and `C` which `A` is the root ViewController, they look like:

```
A => B => C
```

Assume the current presented ViewController is `B`, -if I got it right- you want to present `C` and dismiss `B` at the same time, as I mentioned, dismissing a ViewController (which in this example is `B`) causes to dismiss any ViewController in its hierarchy (which in this example is `C`).

Probably that's not what you want to achieve, if you want to do the following behavior:

*Navigating from `A` to `B`, `B` to `C` and when dismiss `C`, I want to go to `A`, without viewing `B`.*

You need to let `C` ViewController to do this, by implementing:

```
presentingViewController?.presentingViewController?.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
```

This causes to dismiss the presenter of the current presented ViewController of `C` (which is `B`) and back directly to `A`.

For more information about this, you might want to check [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41327216/dismiss-or-remove-previous-modally-presented-view-controller-as-soon-as-the-next/41328245#41328245).

Hope this helped.

Answer (score 0):

You can't dismiss A because it is presenting C. You must dismiss A first, then use the view controller that presented A to present C. Like this:

```
// call this from A
dismiss(animated: false) {
    // completion closure
    self.presentingViewController.present(cViewController, animated: true)
}
```

Answered from my phone, so maybe need some fixes to compile.